# Facebook iOS Graph API Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I want to get info about the Facebook event. I have event's id. I found code like **(1)**, but always getting error:

> FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint '/642xxxxxxxx/event': An open
>   FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.

even if I add some code to open FBSession. Is there any way to do it without FB UI with login user etc. ?

**(1)**

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/642xxxxxxxx/event"
                                      parameters:nil
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                               completionHandler:^(
                                                   FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                   id result,
                                                   NSError *error
                                                   ) {
                                   /* handle the result */
                               }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `642xxxxxxxx` the `event_id`, or a `user_id`? If it's the first case, you just need to call `/642xxxxxxxx`, if it's the last case, you'll need to call `/642xxxxxxxx/events`.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/events/

Comment: It`s the first case, event_id, anyway id results returns me null and same error.